# How to monitor HTTPS traffic using wireshark?

Tags: tls

How do I monitor HTTPS traffic using wireshark?

Comment: While Ráplis answer technically answers the question, I feel like this isn't really what you wanted to know... Do you want to know how to decrypt HTTPS on-the-fly in Wireshark instead?

Comment: https://jimshaver.net/2015/02/11/decrypting-tls-browser-traffic-with-wireshark-the-easy-way/

Answer (score 1):

Type `tcp.port==443` to the search bar to filter the traffic to HTTPS only.

Comment: I type but is not work

Comment: see my updated answer, I tested it as well

Comment: ok thanks Rapil and I wont to monitor packet send and resived using tool or wireshark ,I think i wont syn and act monitor